# Use python return parameter to command line

Tags: python, command-line

I want to build a connection between batch file and python program.

I want to use python to get a parameter which is "abc", and let the batch file use the parameter "abc" to do other thing.

How can I return a parameter to command line in python ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't say what environment you are using (*nix/Windows/OSX etc), but for *nix and shell scripts you can do

```
# Python
# whatever.py
import sys
sys.stdout.write('abc')
sys.exit(0)

# In your shell
OUT=`python whatever.py`
echo $OUT
# Will print abc, and it's stored in the variable `OUT` for later consumption.
```

EDIT (for Windows):

```
# Python
# whatever.py
import sys
sys.stdout.write('abc')
sys.exit(0)

# In a .bat file, or cli.
python whatever.py > temp.txt
set /p OUT=<temp.txt
# Creates/replaces a file called temp.txt containing the output of whatever.py
# then sets the `OUT` var with the contents of it.
```

The Windows way of doing it is not as nice and neat as the *nix way unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

In shell you could always use `-c` switch to execute any command for single run. To explain better,it executes the string in form of python script. So in short it runs the python terminal , does the execution and then terminates the python terminal. Simple as that. Now let me give you some examples for clarification

*Have in mind that i use Windows 10 machine with cmd terminal*

```
python -c "print(__name__)"
```

Returns `__main__` value since i am currently in command prompt. Now this is awesome, since python supports multiliners with **;** after each line so you could theoretically write the whole script as textual file and than execute it with `python -c` with correct version of python installed.

So, in that way you could easily do `python -c "import sys;sys.stdout.write('abc')"` if you wanted.

Now to save it into command variable , i've figured out only 1 way which is bad but if anyone has another. Please comment.

```
python -c "import string;print(dir(string))" >> text.txt
set /p drStr= < text.txt
del text.txt
```

Or in massive oneliner :

```
python -c "import string;print(dir(string))" >> text.txt && set /p drStr= <text.txt && del text.txt
```

now just type `set drStr` to printout the variable and there you go.